# What are visual, logical and pixel bounds of GlyphVector?

Tags: java, awt, glyph

GlyphVector in Java returns 3 types of bounds for entire object.

What are differences between three?

Documentation does not answer these question.

Comment: *"Documentation does not answer these question."*  But drawing them (for a range of letters and words) does.

Comment: Yes but it is not good to deduce everything by experiment.

Comment: I would not try to deduce the meaning of life by experiment - but this, sure.  I think when you *see* the various boxes, it will become obvious what each one does.  A picture paints a thousand words.